# Reagent session not persisting

Tags: session, clojurescript, reagent

In order to know when a user is logged in on my frontend, I check the `:user` key in my Reagent session. I add it to session on /callback like so:

```
(defn callback-page []
  (fn []
    (session/put! :user true)
    (js/setTimeout #(accountant/navigate! (path-for :index)) 3000)
    [:span.main
     [:h1 "Redirecting home..."]]))
```

/callback redirects to the following index page:

```
(defn home-page []
  (if (session/get :user)
    (get-user-info))
  (fn []
    [:span.main
     (if (session/get :user)
       [:h3 (str "Logged in as " (:display_name @user-info))]
       [:p "Not logged in."])]))
```

Once I visit another page, `:user` is no longer in the session. How can I get it to persist across page visits?

Comment: Are you referring to reagent-utils' "session"? https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-utils/blob/master/src/reagent/session.cljs  (Which, by the way, appears to be just an atom... are you doing anything to persist it in browser-local storage?)

Comment: I am not doing anything to persist it in storage. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I feel like this is a bigger question than we can really answer here. Storing state between sessions could mean cookies, localstorage, indexeddb, server side storage, etc. There's not really a "this is how you do it". It's also more of a generalized webdev question than a Reagent question. How you do it in React is going to look very similar to how you do it in Reagent. A good starting point for learning might be: https://pragprog.com/titles/dswdcloj3/web-development-with-clojure-third-edition/